# Using one node for more than one component at WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

At [1] said that for using a distribuited setup is necessary create four directories (one node for store, another for publisher, another for gateway and another for keymanager). My question is:

Is it possible to use just a node for more than one component of the API Manager? For example: one for store and publisher and another for gateway and Keymanager?

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to use one node for more than one component. It's depend on your requirement. Some deployments require publisher to be reside in MZ zone while Store to DMZ. In that case you will need two nodes. Otherwise you can have both store and publisher in single node. It will be same for gateway and keymanager. Depend on your requirement HA requirements you can deploy more than one component in single node.